# python simulador de orbitas no funciona

Tags: python, tkinter

Hice un simulador de orbitas en python, pero no funciona. Los objetos se comportan de forma extraña en vez de atraerse, además de que si tienen mucha masa se van volando hacia el infinito. Aquí está el código:

```
from tkinter import *; import math; import random; import time

root=Tk()
root.geometry("2366x720")

mouseY, mouseX = 0,0

Objectx, Objecty, Objectxvel, Objectyvel, ObjectMass = [],[],[],[],[]

for i in range(3):   # numero objetos
    Objectx.append(random.randint(100,1000))
    Objecty.append(random.randint(100,700))

    Objectxvel.append(0)                #Objectxvel.append(random.randint(-30,30) / 100) 
    Objectyvel.append(0)                #Objectyvel.append(random.randint(-30,30) / 100)

    ObjectMass.append(random.randint(500,500000))


canvas=Canvas(root, bg="white")
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

def mousePos(event):

    global mouseX; global mouseY

    mouseX,mouseY = event.x, event.y

root.bind("<Motion>", mousePos)

mouseMass=0 # masa del circulo rojo. No es importante pero se puede cambiar por diversion

G = 6.67428e-11


while True:

    canvas.delete("all")


#----------------------------- Objects ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    #print(range(len(Objectx)))

    for Num in range(len(Objectx)):


        angle = math.atan2(     mouseY-Objecty[Num], mouseX-Objectx[Num]    )

        distance = math.sqrt( ((mouseX-Objectx[Num])**2) + ((mouseY-Objecty[Num])**2) )


        Objectxvel[Num] += math.cos(angle) * G * ObjectMass[Num] * mouseMass / (distance ** 2)
        Objectyvel[Num] += math.sin(angle) * G * ObjectMass[Num] * mouseMass / (distance ** 2)


        Objectx[Num] += Objectxvel[Num] 
        Objecty[Num] += Objectyvel[Num]


        if distance < 20:
            if distance < 15:

                Objectx[Num] -= Objectxvel[Num] * 1.5
                Objecty[Num] -= Objectyvel[Num] * 1.5
                Objectxvel[Num] = 0
                Objectyvel[Num] = 0
            else:
                Objectx[Num] -= Objectxvel[Num] * 1.01
                Objecty[Num] -= Objectyvel[Num] * 1.01
                Objectxvel[Num] = 0
                Objectyvel[Num] = 0         



        #----------------------------------------------------objects & objects detection--------------------------------------------
        for Num2 in range(len(Objectx)):

            angle = math.atan2(     Objectx[Num]-Objecty[Num2], Objecty[Num]-Objectx[Num2]  )

            distance = math.sqrt( ((Objectx[Num]-Objectx[Num2])**2) + ((Objecty[Num]-Objecty[Num2])**2) )

            #print(distance)
            try:

                Objectxvel[Num] += math.cos(angle) * G * ObjectMass[Num] * ObjectMass[Num2] / (distance ** 2)
                Objectyvel[Num] -= math.sin(angle) * G * ObjectMass[Num] * ObjectMass[Num2] / (distance ** 2)

            except:
                pass



            Objectx[Num] += Objectxvel[Num] 
            Objecty[Num] += Objectyvel[Num]

            if distance < 20 and distance > 0:

                try:

                    Objectx[Num] -= Objectxvel
                    Objecty[Num] -= Objectyvel
                except:
                    pass

                #Objectxvel[Num] = 0
                #Objectyvel[Num] = 0


        canvas.create_oval(Objectx[Num]+5, Objecty[Num]+5, Objectx[Num]-5, Objecty[Num]-5, fill="black", width=0)




#----------------------------- No Object ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    oval1=canvas.create_oval(mouseX+15, mouseY+15, mouseX-15, mouseY-15, fill="red", width=0)

    #print(Objectx, Objecty)

    root.update()
```

PD: para ayudar a entender el código, lo primero que hace es crear listas con valores,como las coordenadas de cada objeto, la fuerza de movimiento en x e y, etc. luego dentro del "While True" tengo un "For Num in range(cantidad de objetos)" que uso para calcular individualmente las físicas de cada objeto con cada objeto, accediendo al elemento número "Num" de cada lista.

PD2:

Objectxvel[Num] += math.sin(angle) * G * ObjectMass[Num] * ObjectMass[Num2] / (distance ** 2) esta es la ley de gravitación universal. Objectx es incrementado
constantemente por Objectxy, el cual es incrementado constantemente por la ley de gravitacion universal. Lo mismo pasa con Objecty e Objectyvel.

Comment: En lugar de poner letras random intenta poner algo mas de explicacion...

Comment: en tu codigo hay muchas cosas confusas, por ejemplo ¿Por que haces la modificación de los parámetros dentro de `if distance < 20:`?, lo mismo para `for Num2 in range(len(Objectx)):
`

Comment: @eyllanesc el if distance es para detectar collisiones, y el for Num2 es para calcular la fuerza gravitatoria entre los objetos

Comment: @Ezequiel En tu publicación solo señalas: "no funciona, bla, bla, no funciona.... codigo... PD: para ejecutar el codigo bla bla", pero en ninguna partes explicas las ecuaciones que gobiernan tu simulación, que elementos interactuan, si deseas obtener la colisión, si hay colisión que debe suceder, etc. Te recomiendo centrarte en explicar tu algoritmo. Ten en cuenta que si no lo señalas explicitamente entonces la comunidad no lo deducira magicamente.

Comment: @eyllanesc ok, voy a editarlo. Las ecuaciones que gobiernan mi ecuación son, la ley de gravitación universal, el "atan", que se usa para calcular angulos, y las funciones trigonometricas coseno y seno, que se usan para calcular orbitas

Comment: No todos conocemos esas ecuaciones necesariamente, ni queremo investigarlas, edita tu pregunta para que toda la informacion este alli.

Comment: @Ezequiel por favor no coloques resuelto a tu pregunta, con marcar como aceptada la respuesta de abulafia alcanza

Comment: @Aprendiz es posible que tu hayas removido la explicacion de atan2 y sqrt? si es así me gustaría saber por qué lo hiciste

Comment: Por qué me pareció respuesta y de ser así pudieras publicarla como tal, de todos modos la intención fue ayudar al formato de la pregunta y recibe mis disculpas si se interpretó de otro modo y que me haya equivocado

Comment: @Aprendiz no te preocupes, simplemente quería saber por qué la editaste

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Que yo vea, hay un error en una de las ecuaciones en que actualizas la velocidad en el eje Y de los objetos, pues usas un `-=` donde debería ser un `+=`.

Corregido ese problema, creo que el código se comporta como debe, si bien caben una serie de observaciones debido a las cuales la animación que obtienes finalmente parece contraintuitiva:

1. Las masas de los puntitos las generas al azar, entre 500 y 500000. Es un rango de variabilidad muy grande. Puedes tener una masa de sólo 500 (que apenas afectaría a las demás) junto a otras de 200000 o más, que dominarían la situación. Pero ya que todas se representan del mismo tamaño en la GUI su comportamiento no será fácil de comprender. Sería mejor que el radio de los puntitos en la representación fuera proporcional por ejemplo a la raiz cúbica de su masa.
2. La masa que gobiernas con el ratón (punto rojo) es cero por defecto. Sin embargo se representa como un punto mucho más gordo que los demás, que parece un sol. Intuitivamente uno esperaría que los "planetas" sufrieran un fuerte tirón gravitatorio por parte de ese "sol", pero al darle masa cero, de hecho es como si no estuviera. De nuevo contraintuitivo.
3. Una vez que uno de los cuerpos se ve atraído por otro, su velocidad se irá incrementando cada vez más, en forma no lineal (pues la aceleración que sufre también va en aumento debido a que las distancias se acortan). En consecuencia la posición de ese objeto se incrementará cada vez más de prisa y, debido a la inercia, incluso después de rebasar al objeto que lo atraía (si no colisonan) saldrá despedido fuera de la pantalla y es probable que no vuelvas a verlo más. La trayectoria de estos objetos podría ser una parábola y no volver a entrar nunca en pantalla, o una elipse muy excéntrica y tardar años en volver (como los cometas). Todo esto puede producir la sensación de que algo está mal y aparentar que las masas se "repelen" en vez de atraerse (esa es la sensación que me produjo a mi en mis primeras simulaciones).

No obstante, creo que todo está correcto. Un comportamiento más normal y menos contraintuitivo se consigue si dotas al "sol" (el cursor del ratón) de una masa mucho mayor que la de los "planetas" y pruebas a acercarlo a ellos para ver cómo se ven atraídos. También puede ayudar mucho el dibujar en cada planeta una flecha-vector que indique la dirección y magnitud de su velocidad, para confirmar que la atracción y la inercia están funcionando como deben. También se puede hacer que el tamaño de cada "planeta" sea proporcional a su masa como antes comenté, lo que puede hacer más intuitivo el comprender sus movimientos.

El siguiente código implementa estas "mejoras" además de corregir el error de signo antes mencionado:

```py
from tkinter import *; import math; import random; import time

root=Tk()
root.geometry("2366x720")

mouseY, mouseX = 0,0
Objectx, Objecty, Objectxvel, Objectyvel, ObjectMass, ObjectR = [],[],[],[],[],[]

for i in range(3):   # numero objetos
    Objectx.append(random.randint(100,1000))
    Objecty.append(random.randint(100,700))
    Objectxvel.append(0)                #Objectxvel.append(random.randint(-30,30) / 100) 
    Objectyvel.append(0)                #Objectyvel.append(random.randint(-30,30) / 100)
    ObjectMass.append(random.randint(500,20000))
    ObjectR.append(ObjectMass[i]**0.3333333)

canvas=Canvas(root, bg="white")
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

def mousePos(event):
    global mouseX; global mouseY
    mouseX,mouseY = event.x, event.y

root.bind("<Motion>", mousePos)
mouseMass=500000 # masa del circulo rojo. No es importante pero se puede cambiar por diversion
G = 6.67428e-11

while True:
    canvas.delete("all")
    for Num in range(len(Objectx)):
        angle = math.atan2(mouseY-Objecty[Num], mouseX-Objectx[Num])
        distance = math.sqrt( ((mouseX-Objectx[Num])**2) + ((mouseY-Objecty[Num])**2) )
        Objectxvel[Num] += math.cos(angle) * G * ObjectMass[Num] * mouseMass / (distance ** 2)
        Objectyvel[Num] += math.sin(angle) * G * ObjectMass[Num] * mouseMass / (distance ** 2)
        Objectx[Num] += Objectxvel[Num] 
        Objecty[Num] += Objectyvel[Num]

        if distance < 20:
            if distance < 15:
                Objectx[Num] -= Objectxvel[Num] * 1.5
                Objecty[Num] -= Objectyvel[Num] * 1.5
                Objectxvel[Num] = 0
                Objectyvel[Num] = 0
            else:
                Objectx[Num] -= Objectxvel[Num] * 1.01
                Objecty[Num] -= Objectyvel[Num] * 1.01
                Objectxvel[Num] = 0
                Objectyvel[Num] = 0         

        for Num2 in range(len(Objectx)):
            angle = math.atan2(     Objectx[Num]-Objecty[Num2], Objecty[Num]-Objectx[Num2]  )
            distance = math.sqrt( ((Objectx[Num]-Objectx[Num2])**2) + ((Objecty[Num]-Objecty[Num2])**2) )
            try:
                Objectxvel[Num] += math.cos(angle) * G * ObjectMass[Num] * ObjectMass[Num2] / (distance ** 2)
                Objectyvel[Num] += math.sin(angle) * G * ObjectMass[Num] * ObjectMass[Num2] / (distance ** 2)
            except:
                pass

            Objectx[Num] += Objectxvel[Num] 
            Objecty[Num] += Objectyvel[Num]

            if distance < 20 and distance > 0:
                try:
                    Objectx[Num] -= Objectxvel
                    Objecty[Num] -= Objectyvel
                except:
                    pass
        sc = 1000 # Escala para el "vector velocidad"
        x, y, r, vx, vy = Objectx[Num], Objecty[Num], ObjectR[Num]//2, Objectxvel[Num], Objectyvel[Num] 
        canvas.create_oval(x+r, y+r, x-r, y-r, fill="black", width=0)
        canvas.create_line(x, y, x+sc*vx, y+sc*vy, arrow=LAST)

    oval1=canvas.create_oval(mouseX+15, mouseY+15, mouseX-15, mouseY-15, fill="red", width=0)
    root.update()
```

Y la siguiente animación muestra cómo estuve "jugando" un poco con el sol (que muevo yo con el ratón) y los planetas (que se mueven según las ecuaciones). No sé por qué a veces dejan un rastro.

[image: Animación]

## Update

Tras un comentario del usuario, reviso el código y efectivamente había más errores en la parte en que se computa la interacción de los cuerpos entre sí. En concreto:

- Ese bucle itera de nuevo por todos los cuerpos, para calcular la fuerza ejercida por cada uno de ellos, pero cada cuerpo debería saltarse a "sí mismo" en ese bucle. Basta comprobar si `Num2==Num` y saltarse ese caso.
- El ángulo estaba mal calculado, al restar la x de un cuerpo con la y del otro. Debe restarse el mismo eje.
- Este bucle que calcula las interacciones con otros cuerpos no debería actualizar la posición de los cuerpos aún, sino sólo calcular el vector aceleración. Ya que según se va iterando sobre cada cuerpo, el vector aceleración se va modificando al tener en cuenta la contribución de cada uno de los otros, lo que va haciendo que el vector velocidad también cambie. Una vez se sale de este bucle interno y se tiene el vector velocidad final, se usa éste para actualizar las posiciones de los cuerpos.
- La parte que hacía algo si la distancia es menor de 20 estaba mal, pues intentaba restar a un número una lista. Esto produciría una excepción que era ignorada por el `except: pass`. Al final vale más quitar esto. Si quisieras simular una colisión tendrías que detectar cuándo la distancia es inferior al radio y en ese caso "fusionar" los dos cuerpos (eliminar uno de ellos de la lista y dejar sólo el otro, pero sumar sus masas), a la vez que deberías calcular la velocidad resultante del que queda por la ley de conservación del momento. Al quitar todo esto, los cuerpos simplemente "se atraviesan", o más bien se consideran masas puntuales de dimensión cero que, aunque se atraen, no pueden chocar.

Es decir, eliminando la parte que interactuaba con el "sol" y dejando sólo el cómputo de las interacciones de los cuerpos entre sí, quedaría como sigue. De paso fijo el valor de `random.seed()` para que el resultado sea repetible y salga siempre el mismo. He encontrado que para un seed 4 sale un resultado interesante. Para otros valores los cuerpos enseguida salían despedidos fuera de imagen. También he cambiado el valor de G, aumentándolo varios órdenes de magnitud para que la animación vaya más rápido, que si no se eterniza.

```py
from tkinter import *; import math; import random; import time
random.seed(4)

root=Tk()
root.geometry("2366x720")

mouseY, mouseX = 0,0
Objectx, Objecty, Objectxvel, Objectyvel, ObjectMass, ObjectR = [],[],[],[],[],[]

for i in range(3):   # numero objetos
    Objectx.append(random.randint(100,1000))
    Objecty.append(random.randint(100,700))
    Objectxvel.append(0)
    Objectyvel.append(0)
    ObjectMass.append(random.randint(500,20000))
    ObjectR.append(ObjectMass[i]**0.3333333)

canvas=Canvas(root, bg="white")
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

def mousePos(event):
    global mouseX; global mouseY
    mouseX,mouseY = event.x, event.y

root.bind("<Motion>", mousePos)
mouseMass=00000 # masa del circulo rojo. No es importante pero se puede cambiar por diversion
G = 6.67428e-7  # Valor original era e-11

while True:
    canvas.delete("all")
    for Num in range(len(Objectx)):
        # Eliminada la parte de interacción con el ratón-sol

        for Num2 in range(len(Objectx)):
            if Num2 == Num:   # Saltarse la interacción consigo mismo
                continue
            angle = math.atan2(Objecty[Num2]-Objecty[Num], Objectx[Num2]-Objectx[Num])
            distance = math.sqrt( ((Objectx[Num]-Objectx[Num2])**2) + ((Objecty[Num]-Objecty[Num2])**2) )
            try:
                Objectxvel[Num] += math.cos(angle) * G * ObjectMass[Num] * ObjectMass[Num2] / (distance ** 2)
                Objectyvel[Num] += math.sin(angle) * G * ObjectMass[Num] * ObjectMass[Num2] / (distance ** 2)
            except:
                pass

        Objectx[Num] += Objectxvel[Num]
        Objecty[Num] += Objectyvel[Num]

        sc = 100 # Escala para el "vector velocidad"
        x, y, r, vx, vy = Objectx[Num], Objecty[Num], ObjectR[Num]//2, Objectxvel[Num], Objectyvel[Num] 
        canvas.create_oval(x+r, y+r, x-r, y-r, fill="black")
        canvas.create_line(x, y, x+sc*vx, y+sc*vy, arrow=LAST)

    oval1=canvas.create_oval(mouseX+15, mouseY+15, mouseX-15, mouseY-15, fill="red", width=0)
    root.update()
```

La animación resultante es ahora:

[image: Animación 2]

(he resuelto el problema del "rastro" que dejaban quitando la opción `width=0` de `create_oval()`)

Comment: muchas gracias por las sugerencias, pero el principal fallo del programa es que los objetos no se atraen entre sí. (esto se puede observar si le fijas la masa al mouse a 0). En vez de atraerse se alejan. Puedes probar si quieres a fijar la masa del mouse a 0 y poner 2 objetos en el canvas, veras que en vez de atraerse van a donde quieren.

Comment: @Ezequiel Tenías razón, había más errores en la segunda parte. Creo que los he corregido en mi actualización de la respuesta

Answer (score 3):

Se me hizo súper interesante el tema, y tuve tiempo libre, por lo que decidí pasarlo a un modelo orientado a objetos de forma que

1. Se pueda mantener el efecto gravitatorio del mouse
2. Sea más simple de leer, desde un punto de programación

Y basado en la [respuesta de abulafia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/291342/131763) (manteniendo los imports y el seed), logré mi objetivo:

**1. Tratar cada "objeto" como una clase (lo llamé Planeta)**

```
class Planeta:
    def __init__(self, x, y, mass, xvel=0, yvel=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.xvel = xvel
        self.yvel = yvel
        self.mass = mass
        self.radius = self.mass**0.3333333
```

Con esto evitas tener que manejar muchas variables en muchas listas, y en su lugar, una lista llena de objetos, y que cada objeto tenga "en su interior" las variables que necesitas (posición, velocidad, masa)

**2. Pasar el simulador a clase**

```
class Simulador:

    planetas = []  # Lista "maestra" de planetas
    sc = 100      # Escala para el "vector velocidad"
    G = 6.67428e-9  # Constante
    mouseY, mouseX = 0, 0
    mouseMass = 50000  # Masa del mouse

    def __init__(self, numObj):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.geometry("2366x720")
        self.root.bind("<Motion>", self.mousePos)
        self.planetaMouse = Planeta(self.mouseX, self.mouseY, self.mouseMass)
        self.crearPlanetas(numObj)
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.root, bg="white")
        self.canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        while True:
            self.actualizar()

    def mousePos(self, event):
        self.mouseX, self.mouseY = event.x, event.y
        self.planetaMouse.x, self.planetaMouse.y = event.x, event.y

    def crearPlanetas(self, n):
        """
        Crea "n" planetas, se agregan a la lista maestra, con valores aleatorios
        """
        for i in range(n):  # numero de planetas
            self.planetas.append(Planeta(random.randint(100, 1000), random.randint(
                100, 700), random.randint(600, 20000)))  # Opcionalmente poner la velocidad x e y, pero va 0 por default

    def actualizar(self):
        self.canvas.delete("all")
        # foreach con enumerate en lugar de for i in range
        for Num, elem in enumerate(self.planetas):
            for Num2, elem2 in enumerate(self.planetas):
                if Num2 == Num:   # Saltarse la interacción consigo mismo
                    continue  # Creo que este if no es necesario, en ese caso, se puede eliminar el Num y el enumerate de los for
                self.calcular(elem, elem2)
            self.calcular(elem, self.planetaMouse)
            elem.x += elem.xvel
            elem.y += elem.yvel
            r = elem.radius//2
            self.canvas.create_oval(
                elem.x + r, elem.y+r, elem.x-r, elem.y - r, fill="black")
            self.canvas.create_line(
                elem.x, elem.y, elem.x+self.sc * elem.xvel, elem.y+self.sc*elem.yvel, arrow=LAST)
        self.oval1 = self.canvas.create_oval(
            self.mouseX+15, self.mouseY+15, self.mouseX-15, self.mouseY-15, fill="red", width=0)
        self.root.update()

    def calcular(self, elem, elem2):
        angle = math.atan2(elem2.y-elem.y, elem2.x-elem.x)
        distance = math.sqrt(
            ((elem.x-elem2.x)**2) + ((elem.y-elem2.y)**2))
        try:
            elem.xvel += math.cos(angle) * self.G * elem.mass * \
                elem2.mass / (distance ** 2)
            elem.yvel += math.sin(angle) * self.G * elem.mass * \
                elem2.mass / (distance ** 2)
        except:
            pass
```

Básicamente, intenté:

- Mantener los nombres de variables, o hacer que sea fácil darse cuenta de qué es cada variable y qué hace cada método
- Eliminar los `for i in range(x)` por un `for each`, para que se vea más *pythónico*
- Aclarar un poco el código relegando el trabajo de cálculos matemáticos a otra función
- Hacer que el mouse sea otro objeto `Planeta`, por lo que simplemente con llamar a la función `calcular()` por cada Planeta, ya se puede apreciar su efecto!

Finalmente, solo quedaría instanciar el simulador (le puse 8 planetas, en este caso):

```
tt = Simulador(8)
```

El resultado es el mismo, solo que el mouse ya afecta a los planetas!

Comment: Bien por tomarte el tiempo de mejorar el diseño! +1 Esto es algo que pensaba mencionar en mi respuesta pero al final no puse. Lo de mantener las variables que afectan a cada planeta separadas en varias listas no era buen diseño, y usar OOP era la elección obvia. Por otro lado, lo de que el sol afecte a los planetas lo había quitado simplemente para mostrar más fácilmente que los planetas sí se atraían entre sí, pero funcionaba también correctamente en la respuesta original, pero convertirle en "un planeta más" es una excelente idea.