# Botones con pygame

Tags: python

tengo la siguiente duda:

Estoy empezando con Python y debo hacer un proyecto en el que debo implementar una interfaz gráfica, para eso estoy usando pygame ya que debo graficar figuras, hacer unas animaciones, etc. Me lo recomendaron por la facilidad y hasta ahora es así. La cuestión es que también debo implementar algunos elementos como botones, listas, campos de texto, pero no encuentro la forma de hacerlo. ¿Se pueden hacer esos elementos con pygame? ¿O debo crearlos con algún otro módulo como pyqt?

Desde ya muchas gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Lo que quieres hacer sería crear una GUI dentro de Pygame. O usar una existente, ya que hay [varias donde elegir](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/gui).

Tratar de mezclar otro framework (pyqt, tkinter...) con pygame es muy complejo, pues cada uno tiene su propio bucle de eventos y casarlos no es sencillo.

Puedes también plantearte rehacerlo todo con uno de estos frameworks, pero quizás las animaciones sean más difíciles de lograr. Depende de su complejidad. La mayoría de frameworks ofrecen un componente llamado *canvas* en el que puedes dibujar libremente lo que quieras, y si eso lo combinas con un borrado previo antes de cada repintado, puedes crear animaciones sencilas. Mira por ejemplo [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/291251/7123) en la que se usa Tkinter para crear una animación de un sistema planetario según las leyes de Newton.